# Can you perform an inclusion validation based on an enum attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have the model `CouponRestriction`, which has the attributes `constraint_type` and `constraint_value`.

`constraint_type` is an integer column (`enum`) and I should validate the value of `constraint_value` based on the `constraint_type` .

For example, if the `constraint_type` is *"periodicity"* I should validate that the `constraint_value` is within an array of given values ["monthly", "yearly"]. But if the `constraint_type` value is something else, the `constraint_value` permitted could be an array of ID's instead of words.

Is there a way to perform such validation depending on the enum column value without writing a custom validation?

I'm trying something like:

```
validates :constraint_value, inclusion: { in: ["week", "month", "year"] }, if: self.constraint_type == "periodicity"
```

but I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method constraint_type for #<Class:0x0000558f3f19c188>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to use a lambda](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)

```rb
validates :constraint_value, 
          inclusion: { in: %w(week month year) }, 
          if: -> { constraint_type == "periodicity" }
```

Comment: The key difference here is that the lamba is called when performing the validations instead of the condition being evaluated when the class is defined. It can actually be any type of callable or a symbol representing a method name.